# Upload csv files from a directory to a folder using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I am trying to upload several csv files (with a specific name) from a directory to a folder in my desktop.

I have tried the below mentioned code but nothing comes up.

```
Sub Copy_Files_Dates()
'This example copy all files between certain dates from FromPath to ToPath.
'You can also use this to copy the files from the last ? days
'If Fdate >= Date - 30 Then
'Note: If the files in ToPath already exist it will overwrite
'existing files in this folder

    Dim FSO As Object
    Dim FromPath As String
    Dim ToPath As String
    Dim Filename As String
    Dim FileInFromFolder As Object

    FromPath = "K:\CIU\Data\FRC\monthly_checks*" & "*.csv*"  '<< Change
    ToPath = "C:\Users\WZHKLXH\Desktop\reporting"    '<< Change

    If Right(FromPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        FromPath = FromPath & "\"
    End If

    If Right(ToPath, 1) <> "\" Then
        ToPath = ToPath & "\"
    End If

    Set FSO = CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject")

    If FSO.FolderExists(FromPath) = False Then
        MsgBox FromPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    If FSO.FolderExists(ToPath) = False Then
        MsgBox ToPath & " doesn't exist"
        Exit Sub
    End If

    For Each FileInFromFolder In FSO.getfolder(FromPath).Files
        Filename = "monthly_checks*" & ".csv" ' or "dd.mm.yy")
        'Copy files from 1-Aug-2020 to 20-Dec-2020
        If Fdate >= DateSerial(2020, 7, 1) And Fdate <= DateSerial(2020, 12, 20) Then
            FileInFromFolder.Copy ToPath
        End If
    Next FileInFromFolder

    MsgBox "You can find the files from " & FromPath & " in " & ToPath

End Sub
```

Comment: Your from path is specifying files so there is no need to add the "\"

Comment: the FromPath string, evaluates to, K:\CIU\Data\FRC\monthly_checks**.csv*, then you append a, "\", which you don't need or want.

Comment: Hi, I removed the "\" but still nothing comes up at the folder

Comment: Where do you specify what is behind Fdate  variable?

Comment: place some Debug.Print variable_name, and break points in yor code, see where it's falling out. does, K:\CIU\Data\FRC\monthly_checks**.csv*, exist? Also, your loop, where does FDate come from? What file date are you getting? Is, FileInFromFolder, a filename or file object? If you can, in your IDE, reference the, Microsoft Scripting Runtime, you'll be able to early bind the filesystem object, hence get intellisense for it.